# vb.net CDN Images Only on Production

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, cdn

Whats the right way to change the url for all the images on my site to use a cdn url or not based on a web.config value.

I have this web.config value

```
<add key="UseCDN" value="1"/>
```

now my page has a whole bunch of <\asp:image imageurl="RELATIVEPATH" tags.

I want them to point to my machine when "useCDN" = 0 and to cdn.com\RELATIVEPATH when "useCDN" = 1

whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Can't you implement this logic in vb in the page_load event?  You can set the imageurl property of your images there.

Comment: I want to implement a site wide solution and it seems expensive to iterate through every control in the page, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

For you to implement a cross cutting solution, you have to extend the image control class and override the Render method to use the use the CDN value (if in production).

Or just create a normal ASCX user control and use it. Can't search now but a simple search will get you plenty of tutorials.

UPDATE:

A [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-user-control-in-aspnet) to help you do it

Comment: maybe you can help me with this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898491/controladapter-only-getting-called-on-first-request

Comment: I don't know what that vb adapter thing is but what you need to achieve what you asked is to create a custom user control: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-user-control-in-aspnet

Comment: You should accept the answer as it is the solution you need.